# What is this "go forward/backward" thing? ........and file switching

Tags: xcode, editor

You know in Xcode, you can press **option - command - left/right arrows** to switch between multiple files. But what are these files?

They seem to be the ones that have been opened. But is there any way to check what they are? And close some unwanted ones.

Or, any other way you know to switch between files??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[alt text http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/8724/picture4asx.png](http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/8724/picture4asx.png)

- if you click on `untitled.m` it will bring up the 'history' although it really functions more like multiple open documents per window.
- The 2 arrows to the left of it are equivalent to the <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd>
- <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> will close the current open document and open the most recent

Answer (score 3):

I dearly miss ctrl+tab for recent document list like in Visual Studio, Eclipse and others. They do it with the application switcher so why not in their editors ? And whats up with "Command + Option + Shift + T" shortcuts ? One thing I have noticed after switching to Mac is the use of lame shortcuts like that, "press cmd+ctrl+option+]+k to open bla bla". Have Apple developers 4 hands or something ? If I want to indent multiple lines it should have been just tab.
Apple and 3rd party developers doesn't seem to follow a standard like they do in the windows world, every app has its own way of doing things.

Answer (score 2):

Your guess about

> They seem to be the ones that have
>   been opened

is correct.

Here is some ways you can use to switch between files.

**^1 popups loaded files**

Command + Option + Up to switch between declaration and implementation files.
Command + Shift + D to quick open project related file.
Command + Option + Shift + T to reveal your file in the group list. And then select related one.

"Popup of include files" is also good one to browse files related to the current one.

"View -> Smart Groups -> All Files | Symbols | etc " and then Tab and type first letters. Tab. And choose one you want. Bind some keys for that.

Answer (score 1):

Simpliest: Two finger swiping on the trackpad left-and-right.

Answer (score 0):

Command + Option + left / right arrows - collapse code

Command + Ctrl + up / down arrows - switch between .h and .m

Command + Ctrl + left / right arrows - move backward / forward